# How to reset a selectmenu inside a modal dialog, using jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI `selectmenu` inside a jQuery modal dialog. I would like to clear the selection of the `selectmenu`, when the modal dialog is closed, whether by the OK or Cancel buttons, or the close box.

I'm trying to update a web app I didn't write to eliminate the use of the jAlert/jConfirm/jPrompt library that seems to have been withdrawn. I built an example that I want to work before I rip apart this app I didn't write to replace many jPrompt calls.

I've demonstrated that I can display the `selectmenu` inside the model dialog, and can return the selection to the modal dialog, where I intend to store it where it is needed.

What I haven't been able to do so far is clear the selection from the `selectmenu`, when the user exits the modal dialog, by clicking the OK or Cancel buttons or the close box. I've tried to apply about a half-dozen suggestions I've found on this site, but none of those work in this case.

I've included my example here:

```
<button id="opener">Change Category</button>
<div id="popup_message" style="display: none;">
  <form id="category_popup">
    <select name="category" id="category">
      <option>Choose a category</option>
      <option value="G1">G1</option>
      <option value="G3">G3</option>
      <option value="C1G1">C1G1</option>
      <option value="C2G1">C2G1</option>
      <option value="C3G1">C3G1</option>
      <option value="C4G1">C4G1</option>
      <option value="C5G1">C5G1</option>
      <option value="C6G1">C6G1</option>
      <option value="C7G1">C7G1</option>
      <option value="C8G1">C8G1</option>
      <option value="C9G1">C9G1</option>
      <option value="C1G3">C1G3</option>
      <option value="C2G3">C2G3</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
  $('#popup_message').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Choose Category',
    buttons: [{
        text: 'OK',
        click: function() {
          alert('Category= ' + $('#category').find(':selected').text());
          $(this).dialog('close');
          return $('#category').val();
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  $('#opener').on('click', function() {
    $('#popup_message').dialog('open');
  });
  $('#popup_message').on('dialogclose', function() {
    // $('#category_popup option').attr('selected',false);
    // $('#category_popup').trigger('reset');
    $('#category').selectmenu('refresh');
    // $(':input','#category_popup').removeAttr('selected');
    // $('#category_popup').val([]);
    truth = true; // to allow a breakpoint here
  });
  $('#category').selectmenu();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the index before like this :

```
$('#popup_message').on('dialogclose', function() {
  // $('#category_popup option').attr('selected',false);
  // $('#category_popup').trigger('reset');
  var myselect = $("select#category");
  myselect[0].selectedIndex = 0;
  myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
  // $(':input','#category_popup').removeAttr('selected');
  // $('#category_popup').val([]);
  truth = true; // to allow a breakpoint here
});
```

Comment: That took care of it. This leads to a question: Is the need to index this because of the possibility of multiple selections?  Thanks for the quick and helpful response